# Can't install cuDNN 5.1.5 with CUDA 8.0 and Tensorflow 0.12 on g2.2xlarge instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, cudnn

The steps I've taken are below.  During the `./configure` step, unless I allow the system default for the cuDNN version (v5) instead of specifying v5.1.5 (as I want), I get an error saying that the environment version (v5) for cuDNN doesn't match the target version (5.1.5).  Since I have downloaded the cuDNN v5.1.5 file for CUDA 8.0 from Nvidia I'm baffled.

What's more, after digging through https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/gpus/cuda_configure.bzl around line 240, I'm seeing that the version the bazel configure script checks against seems to only take into account the Major numeral of the cuDNN version (my Major, Minor and Patch numerals within cudnn.h are 5, 1, 5 respectively).  So, I'm uncertain as to how it would ever allow version 5.1.5 to be installed.  Maybe I'm looking at it wrong?

In any case, does anyone have a method of installing cuDNN 5.1.5 with CUDA 8.0 and Tensorflow 0.12 on a g2.2xlarge instance?

Thanks!

### Steps

### (Note: these work, but it installs cuDNN 5.0, not 5.1.5 as desired)

### Provisioning

- follow provisioning steps from: https://medium.com/@giltamari/tensorflow-getting-started-gpu-installation-on-ec2-9b9915d95d6f#.2hv67eeek
  (i.e. up to but not including: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`)

### Installing dependencies and tools

- familiarize self with:

  - http://expressionflow.com/2016/10/09/installing-tensorflow-on-an-aws-ec2-p2-gpu-instance/
  - http://ramhiser.com/2016/01/05/installing-tensorflow-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-gpu-support/
  - https://alliseesolutions.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/install-gpu-tensorflow-from-sources-w-ubuntu-16-04-and-cuda-8-0-rc/
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential git python-pip libfreetype6-dev libxft-dev libncurses-dev libopenblas-dev gfortran python-matplotlib libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev python-dev python-pydot linux-headers-generic linux-image-extra-virtual unzip python-numpy swig python-pandas python-sklearn unzip wget pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev libcurl3-dev`
- `sudo pip install -U pip`

### Installing Cuda 8

- `wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64-deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64-deb`
- `rm cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64-deb`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y cuda`

### Installing cuDNN

- We want to download and install latest version of cuDNN. Downloading cuDNN requires logging into NVIDIA developer site, so we can’t use wget to fetch the files. Download the following files from NVIDIA and upload them to your AWS instance.
- download cuDNN 5.1 for CUDA 8.0 on linux
- scp -i ssh-key.pem path/to/downloaded/cudnn ubuntu@ec2{instance}.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:~/
- `sudo tar -xzvf cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1.tgz`
- `sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include`
- `sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64`
- `sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*`

### Configure the Environment

- put following at end of `~/.bashrc`:
  `export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda`
  `export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda`
  `export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/bin`
  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_ROOT/lib64:$CUDA_ROOT/extras/CUPTI/lib64`
- `source ~/.bashrc`
- `sudo reboot`

### Installing Bazel

- `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-  set-selections`
- `echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-    set-selections`
- `sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer`
- `sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev`
- scp `https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.3.2/bazel-0.3.2-installer-linux-x86_64.sh` from local machine to ec2 instance
- `chmod +x bazel-0.1.4-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`
- `./bazel-0.1.4-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user`
- `rm bazel-0.1.4-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`
- `bazel version`

### Building and Installing Tensorflow

- `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`
- `cd tensorflow`
- `TF_UNOFFICIAL_SETTING=1 ./configure`
- hit enter/default for all except:

  - CUDA version = 8.0, CUDA dependency = 3.0 (k520 gpu)
- `bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer`
- `bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg`
- `sudo pip install --upgrade /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.12.0rc1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl`

Comment: Have you tried starting with this AMI? https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB#product-description

Comment: No (reviews were less positive when I started this endeavor).  Does that AMI, come with Tensorflow installed from sources?  I need to run inception.

Comment: I am also wary of using Amazon Linux (yum package manager) for deep learning right now...seems like there could arise issues with compatibility and support?  (My background is also mainly Ubuntu)

Comment: It's officially supported by Amazon: http://tothestars.io/blog/2016/10/26/one-click-deep-learning-on-ec2

You could test it out in about five minutes and figure out if it works for you.

Comment: Follow the instructions mentioned in [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu). Thanks!